# how to Count document by oid range with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

i want to count the documents that it's oid between  625d8b000000000000000000 and 625edc800000000000000000
pymongo==3.12.3
mongodb 3.2 and 4.4

i write it like blow:
`counter = coll.count_documents({"_id" : {"$in" : { "$oid" : "625d8b000000000000000000" }, { "$oid" : "625edc800000000000000000" }}})`

i guess that we coud't compare oid with string directly.
it does't work , i don't know what's it rigt syntax really, help pls!

Comment: Have you checked out [$toString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from pymongo import MongoClient

gen_time = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1)
dummy_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(gen_time)
result = collection.find({"_id": {"$lt": dummy_id}})
```

refer: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/objectid.html

Comment: Can you explain why the solution works? It seems it is not searching between 2 boundaries of objectId.

Comment: for example:
query = {'$and': [{'field 1': 'MUST MATCH THIS'}, {'field 2': '..AND THIS!'}]}